# How to find the n value of element that has a class of .foo in the document in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here i have screwed in finding n value of element has my required class . I need to find my 1st element has my class 'active' or 2nd element has ?. how to do that with out for loop.Here is my code

```
var themes = $('.span');
            for(var i=0;i<themes.length;i++){
               if($(themes[i]).hasClass('active')){
                  console.log(i+1);                 
              }           
            }
```

here i can able to find in which place of element has active class.Is it possible.

Comment: You can try `$('.span.active').index()` http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: `for loops` aren't bad and shouldn't be avoided. Many times they're the right tool for the job. The code under the index function is a loop. It's almost the same as the loop you've already written.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
if($('.span.active').length)
   $('.span.active').index()+1;
```

Comment: Ya this is exactly I want.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works as you need:

```
$('.span').each(function(i){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        console.log(i+1);
    }
});
```

That's it.